# Ошибка при установке модуля PynPut

Tags: python, pynput

все методы указанные в других вопросах перепробовал, у меня походу особый случай)

[image: вот код]

через лист показывает что он установлен...

пишет вот так при попытке запуска кода

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Codes\codes\main.py", line 3, in 
from pynput import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

Comment: Устанавливали в тот же интерпретатор, что внизу справа в окне vscode указан?

Comment: Вообще надо взять за привычку работать в виртуальном окружении venv.

Comment: @insolor устанавливал просто через терминал в VS code

Comment: @polosnyak_ vscode никак не контролирует то, в какой интерпретатор будут у вас пакеты ставиться при при запуске pip через его терминал. Нужно или снести все интерпретаторы кроме одного, или проконтролировать, чтобы в PATH был прописан путь именно к нужному интерпретатору, или виртуальное окружение использовать - активировать его в терминале, выбрать справа внизу в окне vscode.

Comment: проблему решил, cпасибо!