Не получается установить pynput
Прошу помощи в установке pynput. Вводил ранее в cmd и в терминале Visual Studio Code разные команды, такие как:
pip install pynput
pip3 install pynput
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install pynput

После этого вписывал from pynput import keyboard, выдавало ошибку

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

Версия питона 3.10.4
Как можно устранить эту ошибку?
так же прилагаю снимок ошибки и кода


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1472667/178576

"Версия питона 3.10.4" но запускаете вы через Python 3.13

Спасибо большое за решение
